# data.table and dplyr compatibility

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, compatibility

When I use both `data.table` and `dplyr`, I got some strange errors.

The packages I have are:

> data.table: '1.12.2'
>
> dplyr: '0.8.3'

If I roll back to older versions, no errors occur. If I use `dplyr` only, no errors occur.

#### Use both data.table and dplyr

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

x1 = data.table(c1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                c2 = c("x", "y", "x", "z", "y", "x", "x"),
                c3 = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 7, 9))
x2 = data.table(c1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                c2 = c("x", "y", "x", "z", "y", "x", "x"),
                c3 = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 7, 9)) 

xx = rbind(x1, x2)
v = xx[c1=="a",]
y = xx[c2=="x",]
w = xx %>%
  select (c1, c2, c3) %>%
  group_by(c1,c2)  %>%
  summarise(c4 = mean(c3))  %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  setDT()
 
View(w[c1=="a",])
```

The line of code `View(w[c1=="a",])` produce the error message:

> Error in View : Internal error: index 'c1' exists but is invalid

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `setDF(ww)` before the first pipe?

Comment: I get the same error. When I load the ```dtplyr``` package, it works without a problem. In fact, you should be loading ```dtplyr``` if you're combining ```data.table``` and ```dplyr``` stuff. Otherwise, you're not really getting any efficiencies.

Comment: Using dtplyr did work. Does that mean there exists a compatibility issue between deplyr and data.table?

Comment: setDF(ww) before the first pipe does not work. I am not really looking for a solution. I am trying to understand what causes the error.

Comment: `setindex(w, NULL)` and then `w[c1 == 'a', ]` would work. It seems that if indices were set before with `data.table` (e.g. when filtering), they don't get removed once the `data.table` class is removed and the object address lost. As for why this happens and whether it is intentional you may want to ask the question on `data.table`'s GitHub.

Comment: This is a bug on `data.table`'s end it seems: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/setkey.R#L133

Comment: Have filed an issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3745